# Model empty when submitting Form to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I get an empty model when i call html.action method,here is my view

```
@model Models.Element.ElementEditModel
    @{
        Layout = null;
    }
     @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Element", FormMethod.Post, new { autocomplete = "off", onsubmit = "return false;" }))
{

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Element", FormMethod.Post, new { autocomplete = "off", onsubmit = "return false;" }))
        {
        if (Model != null)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.style)
        }
               <div>
                    @Html.Partial("Properties/_genre")
                    @Html.Action("Properties", "Option", new { ID = Model.ID })    
                </div>
     <a href="@Url.Action("Save", "Element")"> save</a>
```

if I remove Html.Action it works!

```
  [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult Save( Models.ElementEditModel.ElementEditModel model)
    {...}
```

Comment: Where are you defining the properties in your view?

Comment: Nested forms are invalid and not supported. But `onsubmit = "return false;"` cancels the submit so you never post back the data (and your 'Save' link just calls a GET method does not pass any values to it)

Comment: actually i replaced the save link with a submit button , it works fine if i remove Html.Action from the view ,

Answer (score 1):

1. You have two begin forms. don't do that.
2. Your view's model `@model Models.Element.ElementEditModel` and action's model `Models.ElementEditModel.ElementEditModel model` don't seem to match.
3. you are calling save in an anchor tag which will result in a GET not a POST. use an input with type submit to let the form know to post the data

```
<input id="SaveButton" value="Save" type="submit">
```

Comment: Update question with changes made.